# AWS VPC Architecture Diagram Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services

We just implemented aws-vpc for our Rails app as per scenario 2 
1 public subnet -2 Private subnet.

Now the requirement is to have a Awesome Diagram of it.
Is there any coolest way to get it done automatically.

Answer (score 3):

[Cloudcraft](https://cloudcraft.co/) is a free tool specifically for drawing AWS architecture diagrams.

Example of a AWS diagram with a VPC and multiple subnets:
[image]

Comment: Cool and I started using it...but lacks small things that make life easier, like grouping labels with components. I really need that...

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about the architecture diagram involving the illustration of the subnets and access; I doubt there is anything which automatically does that.

But take a look at the [AWS Simple Icons for Architecture Diagrams](http://aws.amazon.com/architecture/icons/). They provide templates, Visio Stencils, picture tools which are AWS Based Icons. You can use them to create the architecture diagram which you want and it would look professional just like how you see in AWS sites / Documents.

Example ( Taken from the AWS PPTX of the sample Icons )

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Hava : https://hava.io/

You would need to create a read-only IAM user on AWS and they can generate the diagrams automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind with Hava.io is that while you are only giving them read-only access to your AWS account, they can gather full information about the security groups, networking traffic flows and make-up of your infrastructure.

From their homepage:

> Hava assists in network access issues by providing you with real time connectivity flow from subnets to gateways and instances, resource to resource via security groups, and the ability to quickly see which ports are open.